# Does anyone know of a free font with angled, tapered serifs similar to Golden Type Bold?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, free

I'm planning on making invitation cards and a simple webpage for my friend's birthday. I've been trying to find a free webfont alternative for Golden Type Bold for a while. I might just be ok with a desktop font at this point though and finding a separate font for the webpage. Do you guys know of a free substitute for Golden Type? Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Here is a reference: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/golden-type/bold/

[image]

Comment: This font has a number of distinctive features and I doubt you'll find an extremely close match. What attracts you to this font? What features are you less interested in?

Comment: I am most interested in the style of the serifs. I like how most of them are angled and  taper a little bit. Gives it a slight vintage look which I think would work great with the design I'm creating (which is of an  old constellation map).

Answer (score 3):

Coelacanth, a free Venetian based on Centaur, comes in many weights and optical sizes; it’s a work in progress, and the developer’s site is [benwhitmore.altervista.org](http://benwhitmore.altervista.org/).

Here’s a sample for comparison:

```
\documentclass[royal,12pt]{octavo}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Coelacanth Bold Brevier}
\linespread{1.10345}
\begin{document}
\huge
CONSECTETUR ADIP

elit, sed do eiusmod temp

\bigskip

\Large
ELIT, SED DO EIUSMOD TEMPOR

sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut l
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code above]

While we’re on the subject of free Venetians, Ralph Levien is working on Museum ([levien.com/type/myfonts/museum.html](http://levien.com/type/myfonts/museum.html)). It has no bold, but its optical sizes may be useful to you.

Comment: Wow this is very helpful, thank you so much Thérèse!

Comment: Nice find! And all the better that Coelecanth feels (at least to me) like it more consistently meets the OP's requirements than Golden Type (which seems like it can't make up its mind what serifs to use).